# EJB @Local and @Stateless together

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0

I got my work rejected at uni because of using @Local and @Stateless on one EJB. It is a helper bean to validate/fix passed objects.
I think it is completely legal to annotate my ejb's with both local and stateless.
Can someone explain to me why can this be an issue?

Comment: what do you mean by "it is a helper bean to validate/fix passed objects" ?

Comment: you pass to validate method a student object and it validates that no fields are set to null, and if they are it assigns values to them via reflection. Example - name is null - it would be set to String "" .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [javax.ejb.Local](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Local.html) javadoc:

> When used on the bean class, declares the local business interface(s)
>   for a session bean.
>   ... 
>   Use of the Local annotation is only required when the bean class
>   does not implement only a single interface other than any of the
>   following: java.io.Serializable; java.io.Externalizable; any of the
>   interfaces defined in javax.ejb.

So when you use this annotation on the bean class, you need to pass local interface' class as parameter to this annotation.
If your bean exposes a no-interface view you should annotate it with *@LocalBean*. From [javax.ejb.LocalBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/LocalBean.html) javadoc:

> Designates that a session bean exposes a no-interface view. This
>   annotation is required if a session bean exposes any other client
>   views (local, remote, no-interface, 2.x Remote Home, 2.x Local Home,
>   Web Service) in addition to the no-interface view or its implements
>   clause contains an interface other than java.io.Serializable;
>   java.io.Externalizable; or any of the interfaces defined by the
>   javax.ejb package.

So, if your bean doesn't implement any interfaces, you may just annotate it with *@Stateless*:

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB {
    public void localMethod() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your EJB methods are made to be used by a local client (i.e.  if ejb client is in same environment where ejb session bean is to be deployed. ) you have to extract an interface annotated by [@Local](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Local.html) in order to expose your business methods.

Example :

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB implements MyEJBLocal{
    public void myBusinessMethod(){
        //Implementation
    }
}

@Local
public interface MyEJBLocal{
    public void myBusinessMethod();
}
```